# How to differentiate the component function $f(x,y)$ w.r.t the first $n$-tuple $x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $x=(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y=(y_1,y_2, \cdots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be $n$-tuples.

Let $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]^n$ be such that $f(x,y)=(f_1(x_1,y_1),~f_2(x_2,y_2), \cdots, f_n(x_n,y_n))$, where $f_i$ are polynomials in $x_i,y_i$; $i=1,2,...,n$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

> How to differentiate $f(x,y)$ with respect to the first $n$-tuple $x$ ?

From our know vector differentiation formula, we have
\begin{align} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)&=(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x_1,y_1), \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x_2,y_2), \cdots, \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x})(x_n,y_n)) \\ &=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n} \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix} \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & 0& \cdots & 0 \\ 0& \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}& \cdots & 0 \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ 0& 0 & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix},  \end{align}
since each $f_i$ depend on only $x_i$, $y_i$.

Is that good ?

Any comments please

Comment: I think the answer is OK although how you get there is notationally  a bit odd: eg $f_1$ is (as you rightly say) $f_1:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ so it only has two partial derivatives, wrt $x_1,y_1$ - but I know what you mean.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, thanks. Yes, the last sentence was confusing, so I removed it. All I wanted to know about derivative.

Comment: But you have left the meaningless derivative symbols in your proof!

Comment: @ancientmathematician, do you mean $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x}$ ? If so, what else can I use ? Any suggestion please

Comment: No, I mean $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}$ and so on. As $f_1:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ it only has two partial derivatives, one wrt the first coordinate, one wrt the second. It's absolutely clear what you are doing but notationally it seems wrong to me!

Comment: @ancientmathematician, oh I see. So we should have defined $f_i(x_i,y_i)$ as $f_i(0,\cdots,x_i,\cdots,0;0,\cdots,y_i,\cdots,0)$

Comment: The notational problem is that usually when we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ we use $f_i$ to denote the $i$-th component, so that $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}$. If for a moment you replace your $f_i:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi_i$, then in the usual notation we have that $f_i=\phi_i\circ\pi_{i}$ where $\pi_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_i,\dots,y_n)\mapsto(0,\dots,x_i,\dots0,0,\dots,y_i,\dots,0)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, nice. thanks